# What is the Big-O of below code segments

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

These two are two code segments.I want the Big-o of the two code segments seperately with clear explanation.I'm stuck in these.Please don't make this duplicate i just want proper answer.

```
for(int i=1;i<N;i*=2){
       for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
         sum++;

       }


for(int i=1;i<N;i*=2){
       for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
         sum++;

       }
```

Comment: Can you provide your own solution to the problem?

Comment: Of course it won't be closed as duplicate ... because it looks more like it's Off-Topic than duplicate.

Comment: i want a proper explanation with answer

Comment: Your profile says "I love to fail", so how about you provide what you think is a solution, and we help you where you fail. You also say "By day i learn best practices of a programmer", and in this case best practices is to present your solution, the work you've done, rather than demanding a solution.

Comment: first one linear and other one linearithmatic,how it is possible?

Comment: in first one if i think N=100,then i have outer loop runs 1,4,8,16 ,32,64.then inner loop also same then how it is linear.Is it logN*logN

Comment: It sounds like you're just guessing. Perhaps start with cases when N is a power of 2 -- you can compute the final `sum` exactly then, which should give you insight into the solution for all N.

Comment: This question covers/test the concepts for calculating time complexity pretty well and it doesn't deserve a downvote, hence it would be better you, @kalsaraMagamage , can frame it in bit different way. Also please accept my answer if no doubts

Answer (score 2):

First One :

```
for(int i=1;i<N;i*=2){
       for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
         sum++;

       }
```

here we go,

For the outer loop `for(int i=1;i<N;i*=2)` Time Complexity : Order log(N)
ex. to reach i=16, when N = 17, loop would run for 5 times

Now Lets calculate the total time complexity/elements generated in terms of N

```
Outer Loop iteration number | Number of elements generated inside the Inner loop | Power of 2
--------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------- | -----------
1 | 1 | 0
2 | 2 | 1
3 | 4 | 2
4 | 8 | 3
```

And so on

So roughly total elements generated by outer-inner loop with log(N) iterations of Outer loop are

∑ <sub>k=0</sub> <sup>k=Log(N)</sup> 2 <sup>k</sup>

When you solve this you get that the solution for this is in order N

Hence, combining the two loops you get :
N

Second One is pretty straight forward -

```
for(int i=1;i<N;i*=2){
       for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
         sum++;

       }
```

Outer Loop : Log(N)

Inner Loop : N

Hence total : N Log(N)

Comment: can you explain the above table more .@lorenzo

Comment: It shows the iteration that goes in the outer loop along with the number of elements that are generated in the inner loop.I have basically calculated the total elements that are gonna be generated in terms on N, which gives me the TC